# Python subprocess check C++ output not working

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I am using Python subprocess Popen to get the output of a C++ program (a.out) and return it to a website. Here's my code for checking output:

```
        p = Popen(['a.out'], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE)
        final=""
        for ii in range(2):
            value = "12" + '\n'
            value = bytes(value, 'UTF-8')
            p.stdin.write(value)
            p.stdin.flush()
            result = p.stdout.readline().strip()
            final=str(result)+"\n"
```

Here is my C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    for( int ii=0; ii<2; ++ii ){
        int input;
        std::cin >> input;
        std::cout << input << std::endl;
        std::cout.flush();
    }
}
```

When I return `final`, however, It returns an empty string. Why is `final` empty? Shouldn't it contain the C++ output?

a.out was created previously, and the following code was used to create it:

```
r=open("cpp_input.txt", "r")
py_output = subprocess.check_output(['g++', 'try_cpp.cpp'], stdin=r, timeout=problem.timelimit)
```

cpp_input.txt contains the same input, but I run this to make the a.out file.

Comment: You should be concatenating to `final` with `final +=`. You're replacing it each time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar I added that, thank you, but now I get this error in Python (using that same C++ code):
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Comment: That should only happen if the subprocess exits and you try to write to its stdin. It shouldn't happen here because you write and read 2 times in both.